# What happens if I deactivate RSO after the map is generated?

Tags: factorio

I created a map with the RSO mod installed a bit ago, but now that version 0.13 is out the mod is deactivated. Now, the RSO mod should only affect map generation, but I'm not sure how this works for tiles that aren't discovered yet. Factorio has infinite map size, so I'm not sure it precalculates everything or if anything happens dynamically when you discover new tiles.

Will newly discovered areas continue to be created by the rules of the RSO mod even now that it is deactivated, or will they be created with the vanilla game rules?

Comment: Does the game even let you load a save game if any of the mods are disabled?  I thought it didn't.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I didn't have any issue with that. I checked my saves, and it looks like at some point RSO simply wasn't listed as a mod in the saves anymore, while it was still listed in my earlier saves.

Answer (score 2):

Newly discovered by player/revealed by radar/covered with pollution tiles will be created using the algorithm available to the game at that point in time which naturally is Vanilla.
Judging from the code of RSO 2.0.1 it only messes with [Autoplacer](https://wiki.factorio.com/index.php?title=Types/AutoplaceSpecification) that is responsible for new chunks generations, hence in RSO absence the vanilla autoplacer configs should apply.